# Creating and comparing two sets of cards

Tags: c++, arrays, compare

How would I go about creating a hand of cards based on the code below and then comparing them without changing too much of what I have already? I am thinking about how to go about this and am thinking of creating an array for each hand and then populating each hand with 5 cards. Example:

```
int handCard[5];         //creating the "hand of cards"
int otherHand[5];

handcard.getAcard[5];    //adding 5 cards to each hand
otherHand.getAcard[5];

if (handCard[5] < otherHand)    //comparing hands
   cout << "Other hand is stronger" << endl;
if (handCard[5] > otherHand)
   cout << "Hand card is stronger" << endl;
else
   cout << "Both hands are the same in value" << endl;
```

would something like that work? I am afraid of changing the code (I usually end up messing it all up and having to recode the whole thing) I currently have as I am already done with what the assignment asks for but I want try comparing the two hands. I've seen some code on other sites that are for poker and tried to mimic but I think I don't have the proper functions to go about how the other sites went about this. I have only been trying c++ for around 3-4 months so I am not too learned. If there are any other suggestions to make my code more efficient, please let me know. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

const int suit1(4);
const int rank1(13);
const string SUIT[suit1] = { "S", "H", "D", "C" };
const string RANK[rank1] = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" };

class CARD
{
friend class DECK;

public:
explicit CARD();
explicit CARD(int Suit, int Rank);

const string CardString();

const int generate_suite();
const int generate_rank();
const int get_suite();
const int get_rank();

private:
int card_suit;
int card_rank;
};

class Deck
{
public:
explicit Deck();
const void print_Deck();
void getACard();
void shuffle();
private:
vector<CARD> cards_deck;
};

int main()
{
   srand(time(NULL));

   Deck _deck;
   cout << "****NOTE*****" << endl;
   cout << " 'C' Stands for Club, 'S' Stands for Spade, " << endl;
   cout << " 'D' Stands for Diamond, and 'H' Stands for Heart." << endl;

   cout << endl;

   cout << "After shuffling, the cards are: " << endl;
   _deck.shuffle();
   _deck.print_Deck();

   cout << "Your cards are: " << endl;
   for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
   {
       _deck.getACard();
   }

   cout << "The computers cards are: " << endl;
   for (int index1 = 0; index1 < 5; index1++)
   {
       _deck.getACard();
   }

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

CARD::CARD()
{
   card_suit = generate_suite();
   card_rank = generate_rank();
}

CARD::CARD(int Suit, int Rank) : card_suit(Suit), card_rank(Rank)
{

}

const int CARD::generate_suite()
{
    return rand() % (suit1 - 1) + 0;
}

const int CARD::generate_rank()
{
    return rand() % (rank1 - 1) + 0;
}

const string CARD::CardString()
{
   return SUIT[get_suite()] + RANK[get_rank()];
}

const int CARD::get_suite()
{
   return card_suit;
}

const int CARD::get_rank()
{
   return card_rank;
}

Deck::Deck()
{
   for (unsigned int i(0); i < suit1; i++)
{
    for (unsigned int j(0); j < rank1; j++)
    {
        CARD Card(i, j);
        cards_deck.push_back(Card);
    }
}
}

const void Deck::print_Deck()
{
   unsigned int count(1);

   for (unsigned int i(0); i < cards_deck.size(); i++)
   {
    cout << cards_deck[i].CardString() << " ";
    if (count = 13)
    {
        cout << endl;
        count = 0;
    }
    count++;
}
}

void Deck::getACard()
{
   CARD r(cards_deck.back().get_suite(), cards_deck.back().get_rank());
   cards_deck.pop_back();
   cout << r.CardString() << endl;
}

void Deck::shuffle()
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   random_shuffle(cards_deck.begin(), cards_deck.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your syntax is a little off.

```
int handCard[5];
```

should be:

```
CARD handCard[5];
```

Also, you're `getACard` function would need to return the retrieved card, instead of being void.

```
handCard.getACard[5]
```

doesn't do anything because handCard is an `int`. Changing it to a card doesn't do anything, because card doesn't have a function. And, lastly, `getACard` doesn't take a value in. You'll need to write a function like:

```
vector<CARD> Deck::getACard(int numCards);
```

Lastly, the '<' and '>' symbols don't know anything about poker hands. You'll want to come up with a function like:

```
int Deck::comparePokerHands(vector<Card> hand1, vector<Card> hand2);
```

That function can return -1 if hand1 is the winner, 1 if hand2 is the winner, or 0 if the hands are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly compare arrays. And anyway, `if (handCard[5] < otherHand)` is incorrect since you try to compare a single value (`handCard[5]`) to an array (`otherHand)`.

You should create a new class :

```
class Hand {
    Card cards[5];

public:
    // constructors, destructors and other stuff you could need

    void loadFromDeck(Deck& deck) {
       // provided Deck::getACard() returs a Card - it currently does not !
       for (int i=0; i<5; i++) cards[i] = deck.getACard();
    }

    bool operator < (const Hand& other) const {
        bool cr;
        // implement hand comparison
        return cr;
    }
}
```

You could then do :

```
Hand hand;
Hand otherHand;

hand.loadFromDeck(_deck);
otherHand.loadFromDeck(_deck);

if (hand < otherHand) {
    ...
```